# $.getJSON and for loop with an array and how to get them to work together - for loop completes before JSON is returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to cycle through an array and with each value in the array, use `$.getJSON` to return some JSON and populate an HTML table with the return values.

I have been following this post, but seem not get this to work:

[$.getJSON calls misbehaving inside a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287594/getjson-calls-misbehaving-inside-a-for-loop)

Here is my function:

```
$("#selectProviderTop").click(function() {
    var restURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port == "" ? "" : (":" + window.location.port)) + "/restGetProvider/";
    var selected = [];
    var providerKey;
    var providerID;
    var providerLegacyID;
    var providerName;
    var finalURL;
    var tr;

    // First, create an array from the User Provider Keys...
    var userProviderKeys = $("#hiddenUserProviderKeys").val();
    selected = userProviderKeys.split(",");
    console.log("selected: " + selected);

    var tableHTML = "";
    var focus = $("<div></div>"); // either match an existing element or create one: '<div />'

    var arrayLength = selected.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            console.log("i: " + i);

            providerKey = selected[i];
            console.log("providerKey: " + providerKey);
            // Get that provider and populate the table...
            finalURL = restURL + providerKey;
            console.log("finalURL: " + finalURL);
            focus.queue('apicalls', function(next) {
                $.getJSON(finalURL, function(jsonObject) {
                    tableHTML += "<tr>";
                    tableHTML += "<td><a href=\"#\" onclick='selectProvider(\"" + providerKey + "\")'>" + jsonObject["providerName"] + "</a></td>";
                    tableHTML += "<td>" + jsonObject["providerID"] + "</td>";
                    tableHTML += "<td>" + jsonObject["providerLegacyID"] + "</td>";
                    tableHTML += "</tr>";
                    console.log("tableHTML: " + tableHTML);
                    next();
                });
            });
        })(i);
    }

    // Replace table’s tbody html with tableHTML...
    console.log("final tableHTML: " + tableHTML);
    $("#tableProviderSelect tbody").html(tableHTML);

    $('#modalSelectProviderForPTP').modal('show');

});
```

The userProviderKeys value is `0be32d8057924e718a8b6b4186254756,2dc5f826601e4cc5a9a3424caea4115f`

The code never makes the `$.getJSON` call it just completes the for loop.

How do I update this code to get the first value in the array, grab the JSON, create the HTML, and then cycle through the loop?

I have tried `setTimeout` but that didn't help me out.

If you have some ideas, could you update my existing code - I understand better when I see the code itself.  Thanks.

Comment: You're using ajax, and ajax is asynchronous. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/215552 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/215552

Comment: It looks like you're missing a call to `focus.dequeue('apicalls')`

Comment: @sunshine Reading the docs, I think that calling the `next` function as OP has done is equivalent to call the `.dequeue` method.

Comment: You need the initial call to start processing through the queue. This is just what I am inferring from the SO answer that he references, where there is a call to `dequeue` at the end which isn't present in his snippet.

Comment: @Sunshine Interesting... But from that link it looks like you only need to explicitly call `.dequeue` once to get things started, as long as you call the `next` functions when necessary. I'll change my answer to take this into account.

Comment: Why not simply add one more step to the queue?

Comment: @KevinB Like in my answer?

Comment: @DavidKnipe yeah, but i'm more interested in why that approach wasn't taken.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you're doing this using queues. But you are, so I'm not going to rewrite your code to do it some other way.

The last few lines need to be called after all the queued functions have run, which means they should be called asynchronously. (Yes, you could make the whole thing synchronous as Marcus Höglund suggested, but that's no way to write scalable applications in javascript.) You could do this by adding another function to the queue containing these lines. Like this:

```
$("#selectProviderTop").click(function() {
    var restURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + (window.location.port == "" ? "" : (":" + window.location.port)) + "/restGetProvider/";
    var selected = [];
    var providerKey;
    var providerID;
    var providerLegacyID;
    var providerName;
    var finalURL;
    var tr;

    // First, create an array from the User Provider Keys...
    var userProviderKeys = $("#hiddenUserProviderKeys").val();
    selected = userProviderKeys.split(",");
    console.log("selected: " + selected);

    var tableHTML = "";
    var focus = $("<div></div>"); // either match an existing element or create one: '<div />'

    var arrayLength = selected.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        (function(i) {
            console.log("i: " + i);

            providerKey = selected[i];
            console.log("providerKey: " + providerKey);
            // Get that provider and populate the table...
            finalURL = restURL + providerKey;
            console.log("finalURL: " + finalURL);
            focus.queue('apicalls', function(next) {
                $.getJSON(finalURL, function(jsonObject) {
                    tableHTML += "<tr>";
                    tableHTML += "<td><a href=\"#\" onclick='selectProvider(\"" + providerKey + "\")'>" + jsonObject["providerName"] + "</a></td>";
                    tableHTML += "<td>" + jsonObject["providerID"] + "</td>";
                    tableHTML += "<td>" + jsonObject["providerLegacyID"] + "</td>";
                    tableHTML += "</tr>";
                    console.log("tableHTML: " + tableHTML);
                    next();
                });
            });
        })(i);
    }

    focus.queue('apicalls', function(next) {
        // Replace table’s tbody html with tableHTML...
        console.log("final tableHTML: " + tableHTML);
        $("#tableProviderSelect tbody").html(tableHTML);

        $('#modalSelectProviderForPTP').modal('show');

        next();
    });
});
```

**Edit:** Sunshine has pointed out that the linked stackoverflow post has mysterious references to the `.dequeue` method. In the accepted answer, this method is called explicitly after the tasks have been queued. I don't know whether this was necessary or not. I had thought that the problem was that the `$.json` bit wasn't happening until after the `$("#tableProviderSelect tbody").html(tableHTML);` part. But now I realise you wrote: "The code never makes the `$.getJSON` call it just completes the for loop." In that caseSunshine may have been right, and you need to add `focus.dequeue('apicalls');` just after the last `focus.queue(...);`.

Comment: You could also just do `.promise('apicalls').done(...`